# Extract features from 2 auto-encoders and feed them into an MLP

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, autoencoder

I understand that the features extracted from an auto-encoder can be fed into an mlp for classification or regression purpose. This is something that I did earlier.
But what if I have 2 auto-encoders? Can I extract the features from the bottleneck layers of 2 auto-encoders and feed them into an mlp which performs classification based on these features? If yes, then how? I am not sure how to concatenate these two feature sets. I tried with numpy.hstack() which gives me 'unhashable slice' error, whereas, using tf.concat() gives me the error 'Input tensors to a Model must be Keras tensors.' the bottleneck layers of the two auto-encoders are of dimension (None,100) each. So, essentially, if I stack them horizontally, I should be getting a (None, 200). The hidden layer of the mlp may contain some (num_hidden=100) neurons. Could anyone please help?

```
x1 = autoencoder1.get_layer('encoder2').output
x2 = autoencoder2.get_layer('encoder2').output

#inp = np.hstack((x1, x2))
inp = tf.concat([x1, x2], 1)
x = tf.concat([x1, x2], 1)
h = Dense(num_hidden, activation='relu', name='hidden')(x)
y = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='prediction')(h)
mymlp = Model(inputs=inp, outputs=y)

# Compile model
mymlp.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train model
mymlp.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=20, batch_size=8)
```

updated as per @twolffpiggott's suggestion:

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Dropout
from keras import layers
from keras.models import Model
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np

x1 = Data1
x2 = Data2
y = Data3

num_neurons1 = x1.shape[1]
num_neurons2 = x2.shape[1]

# Train-test split
x1_train, x1_test, x2_train, x2_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x1, x2, y, test_size=0.2)

# scale data within [0-1] range
scalar = MinMaxScaler()
x1_train = scalar.fit_transform(x1_train)
x1_test = scalar.transform(x1_test)

x2_train = scalar.fit_transform(x2_train)
x2_test = scalar.transform(x2_test)

x_train = np.concatenate([x1_train, x2_train], axis =-1)
x_test = np.concatenate([x1_test, x2_test], axis =-1)

# Auto-encoder1

encoding_dim1 = 500
encoding_dim2 = 100

input_data = Input(shape=(num_neurons1,))
encoded = Dense(encoding_dim1, activation='relu', name='encoder1')(input_data)
encoded1 = Dense(encoding_dim2, activation='relu', name='encoder2')(encoded)
decoded = Dense(encoding_dim2, activation='relu', name='decoder1')(encoded1)
decoded = Dense(num_neurons1, activation='sigmoid', name='decoder2')(decoded)

# this model maps an input to its reconstruction
autoencoder1 = Model(inputs=input_data, outputs=decoded)
autoencoder1.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mse')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

# training
autoencoder1.fit(x1_train, x1_train,
                    epochs=100,
                    batch_size=8,
                    shuffle=True,
                    validation_data=(x1_test, x1_test))

# Auto-encoder2

encoding_dim1 = 500
encoding_dim2 = 100

input_data = Input(shape=(num_neurons2,))
encoded = Dense(encoding_dim1, activation='relu', name='encoder1')(input_data)
encoded2 = Dense(encoding_dim2, activation='relu', name='encoder2')(encoded)
decoded = Dense(encoding_dim2, activation='relu', name='decoder1')(encoded2)
decoded = Dense(num_neurons2, activation='sigmoid', name='decoder2')(decoded)


# this model maps an input to its reconstruction
autoencoder2 = Model(inputs=input_data, outputs=decoded)
autoencoder2.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mse')

# training
autoencoder2.fit(x2_train, x2_train,
                    epochs=100,
                    batch_size=8,
                    shuffle=True,
                    validation_data=(x2_test, x2_test))

# MLP

num_hidden = 100

encoded1.trainable = False
encoded2.trainable = False

encoded1 = autoencoder1(autoencoder1.inputs)
encoded2 = autoencoder2(autoencoder2.inputs)

concatenated = layers.concatenate([encoded1, encoded2], axis=-1)
x = Dropout(0.2)(concatenated)
h = Dense(num_hidden, activation='relu', name='hidden')(x)
h = Dropout(0.5)(h)
y = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='prediction')(h)
myMLP = Model(inputs=[autoencoder1.inputs, autoencoder2.inputs], outputs=y)

# Compile model
myMLP.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Training
myMLP.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=200, batch_size=8)

# Testing
myMLP.predict(x_test)
```

giving me an error: unhashable type: 'list' from the line:
myMLP = Model(inputs=[autoencoder1.inputs, autoencoder2.inputs], outputs=y)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're mixing numpy arrays with keras tensors. This can't go.

There are two approaches.

- Predict numpy arrays from each autoencoder, concat the arrays, send them to the third model
- Connect all models, probably make the autoencoders untrainable, fit with one input for each autoencoder.

Personally, I'd go for the first. (Assuming the autoencoders are already trained and don't need change).

### First approach

```
numpyOutputFromAuto1 = autoencoder1.predict(numpyInputs1)    
numpyOutputFromAuto2 = autoencoder2.predict(numpyInputs2)

inputDataForThird = np.concatenate([numpyOutputFromAuto1,numpyOutputFromAuto2],axis=-1)

inputTensorForMlp = Input(inputsForThird.shape[1:])
h = Dense(num_hidden, activation='relu', name='hidden')(inputTensorForMlp)
y = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='prediction')(h)

mymlp = Model(inputs=inputTensorForMlp, outputs=y)

....
mymlp.fit(inputDataForThird ,someY)
```

### Second Approach

This is a little more complicated, and at first I don't see much reason to do this. (But of course there may be cases where it's a good choice)

Now we're totally forgetting numpy and working with keras tensors.

Creating the mlp on its own (good if you will use it later without the autoencoders):

```
inputTensorForMlp = Input(input_shape_compatible_with_concatenated_encoder_outputs)
x = Dropout(0.2)(inputTensorForMlp)
h = Dense(num_hidden, activation='relu', name='hidden')(x)
h = Dropout(0.5)(h)
y = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='prediction')(h)
myMLP = Model(inputs=[autoencoder1.inputs, autoencoder2.inputs], outputs=y)
```

We probably want the bottleneck features of the autoencoders, right? If you happened to create the autoencoders properly with: encoder model, decoder model, join both, then it's easier to use just the encoder model. Else:

```
encodedOutput1 = autoencoder1.layers[bottleneckLayer].outputs #or encoder1.outputs
encodedOutput2 = autoencoder1.layers[bottleneckLayer].outputs #or encoder2.outputs
```

Creating a joined model. The concatenation must use a keras layer (we're working with keras tensors):

```
concatenated = Concatenate()([encodedOutput1,encodedOutput2])
output = myMLP(concatenated)

joinedModel = Model([autoencoder1.input,autoencoder2.input],output)
```

Comment: I guess, you meant    mymlp = Model(inputs=inputTensorForMlp, outputs=y) ?

Comment: Thanks a ton @Daniel. It works perfectly fine. However, I am still trying to get 2nd method working.

Comment: sorry, some clarification required. for the 1st approach, you mentioned - `numpyOutputFromAuto1 = autoencoder1.predict(numpyInputs1);      
numpyOutputFromAuto2 = autoencoder2.predict(numpyInputs2)`
How is mymlp getting reduced features then? [read: semicolon=newline]

Comment: I thought, using something like `input_data = Input(shape=(num_neurons1,));           
encoded = Dense(encoding_dim1, activation='relu', name='encoder1')(input_data);          
encoded1 = Dense(encoding_dim2, activation='relu', name='encoder2')(encoded);                      encoder = Model(inputs=input_data, outputs=encoded1);          encoder.predict(numpyInputs)` would give reduced features. Please let me know where I am going wrong. But what would I use as x_test while testing the model - mymlp.predict(???,y_test) [semicolon for newline]

Comment: You described the first approach perfectly. But if you intend to train the encoder, you need to associate it with the decoder and use `y = x`.

Comment: in `mymlp.predict(???,y_test)` you will use `x = encoder.predict(x_test)`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd also go with Daniel's first approach (for simplicity and efficiency), but if you're interested in the second; for instance if you're interested in running the network end-to-end, you'd approach it like this:

```
# make autoencoders not trainable
autoencoder1.trainable = False
autoencoder2.trainable = False

encoded1 = autoencoder1(kerasInputs1)
encoded2 = autoencoder2(kerasInputs2)

concatenated = layers.concatenate([encoded1, encoded2], axis=-1)
h = Dense(num_hidden, activation='relu', name='hidden')(concatenated)
y = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='prediction')(h)

myMLP = Model([input_data1, input_data2], y)

myMLP.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Training
myMLP.fit([x1_train, x2_train], y_train, epochs=200, batch_size=8)

# Testing
myMLP.predict([x1_test, x2_test])
```

**Key edits**

1. The weights of both autoencoders should be frozen end-to-end (otherwise early-stage gradient updates from the randomly initialized MLP will likely result in the loss of much of their learning).
2. The autoencoder input layers should be assigned to separate variables `input_data1` and `input_data2` per autoencoder (instead of both to `input_data`). Even though `autoencoder1.inputs` returns a tf tensor, this is the source of the `unhashable type: list` exception, and replacing with `[input_data1, input_data2]` solves the issue.
3. When fitting the MLP for the end-to-end model, the input should be a list of `x1_train` and `x2_train` rather than the concatenated inputs. Same when predicting.

Comment: Thanks @twolffpiggott for the suggestion. Do you mean I should freeze the weights of the final encoder layers in both the autoencoders? I have updated my question to share the code snippet. Still getting an error - unhashable type: 'list'.

Comment: You mentioned - encoded1 = autoencoder1(kerasInputs1)
encoded2 = autoencoder2(kerasInputs2). Can I use encoded1 = autoencoder1.get_layer('encoder2').output and 
    encoded2 = autoencoder1.get_layer('encoder2').output instead of what you mentioned? What difference will it make?

Comment: The usefulness of this approach is building an end-to-end model which you can feed the original inputs to your autoencoders. This means composing both full autoencoder models with the dense layers. This also allows you to intelligently retrain the autoencoder weights with respect to the MLP objective if you want to.  The alternative approach you mention is along the lines of Daniel's first approach.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.